# Thymeleaf HashMap Request Binding

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Is it possible to map request from Thymeleaf page to model object without editor/converter?

I have a simple simple Thymeleaf page where I am trying to bind a map to a request:

```
@PostMapping("/someendpoint")
public String method1(CustomRequest map, ModelMap model){
    System.err.println("Received: " + map);
    return "demo";
}
```

My CustomRequest POJO is simple:

```
public class CustomRequest {

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
//constructors and getters/setters

}
```

My Thymeleaf page is even simpler:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/someendpoint}" th:object="${customRequest}" method="post">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{map}" />
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Send" /></td>
</form>
```

When I submit the form, I get this error:

> Field error in object 'customRequest' on field 'map': rejected value [{"a":"b"}]; codes [typeMismatch.customRequest.map,typeMismatch.map,typeMismatch.java.util.Map,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [customRequest.map,map]; arguments []; default message [map]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'map'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'map': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]

Is it possible to do it without editor/convertor? Is is possible to directly map request body to `Map`?

Comment: Do you have any other fields in you `CustomRequest` type; if not then just bind your `map` field as a `Map` type.

Comment: Can you explain it? I don't understand.